# Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Ajuda com o erro no `MySql`

```
create table cliente(
    endereco varchar(256),
    codigo integer primary key auto_increment,
    telefone varchar (18),
    tipo varchar(20)
);

create table fisica(
    cpf varchar(20),
    foreign key(cpf) references cliente(tipo)
);
```

Comment: Qual o erro que esta dando ao executar esses comandos?

Comment: Por que você possui uma tabela que só possui uma coluna, que inclusive é chave estrangeira para outra? Não faz sentido essa tabela existir, inclusive associando CPF ao tipo. Adiantando, para você criar uma chave estrangeira, a coluna na outra tabela precisa ser chave primária. O que exatamente está tentando fazer? Não ficou claro na sua pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Todo cliente é uma pessoa (Pode ser Física ou Jurídica);
2. Toda pessoa tem um tipo (Física ou Jurídica);

Criei uma modelagem parecida com a sua mas, com alguns ajustes:

Abaixo o script para criação dos objetos:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Cliente` (
  `codigo` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero_contrato` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtcadastro` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dtrescisao` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `pessoa` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
  INDEX `fk_cliente_01_idx` (`pessoa` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente_01`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pessoa`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Pessoa` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Pessoa` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cpf_cnpj` VARCHAR(14) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `logradouro` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `complemento` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_pessoa_01_idx` (`tipo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pessoa_01`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tipo`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TipoPessoa` (`codigo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TipoPessoa` (
  `codigo` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Apenas uma dica pesquise mais sobre MER (Modelo Entidade e Relacionamento), e procure utilizar ferramentas para a modelagem, no caso do MySql você pode utilizar o Workbench não sei se conhece: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ ele lhe dará uma visão melhor do seu projeto :)

Espero que isso lhe ajude!